# How can I unmap Mod4+S and Mod4+M in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable Mod4+S?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41993/how-to-disable-mod4s)

<kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (or Super+S and Super+M) are mapped to invoking the session management menu (on the rightmost of the GNOME panel), and to minimizing the current window. How can I disable them? They are not shown in System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.

Comment: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41993/how-to-disable-mod4s).